# How can I manage the variables if my C program has a lot of variables

Tags: c

I have been learning C myself, now am trying making a text based game that deals with a lot of variables. What are the best ways to manage my sources and variables? I have considered using a header file and put all my variables there.

Also is there a way I can create functions that can create variables that can be used outside the function, like on the main program?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Typo fixes

Comment: Organize related variables onto structures.

Comment: Generally speaking it is not advisable to have all variables as global variables clustered in a single header file. You should make yourself a plan what variable will be used in which scope and try to keep it as local to that scope as possible. E.g. sort them depending on purpose as local, class wide or with different header files that are not all included everywhere. Structs also help to keep track of the variables. For dynamic memory management have a look at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_memory_management.htm

Comment: Only declare and initialize you variables when you need them, and within the function loop or condition which uses them.

Comment: Divide your program into modules (a pair of .c and .h files), with their own designated functionality. Allocate the variables in the module where they belong. You should _never_ put variable declarations in header files.

Comment: Anyway this question is far too broad for this site without a specific example in mind. It is also opinion-based as you ask for "the best ways" without specifying a criteria. Either of those will lead to the question getting closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Organize variables which have meaning together to one group of structure.

```
struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

Then use this:

```
struct point p;
p.x = 10;
p.y = 20;
```

Memory usage is still the same but you have organized a lot of variables together. Later, you can easily use them as parameters to functions as pointers.

```
int get_distance(struct point* p) {
    return ...
}
```

instead of

```
int get_distance(int x, int y) {
    ...
}
```

Why are structure also handy. If you have setup of variables and functions which accept pointer to structure, you can easily modify structure content (parameters) and function will stay remain.

If you want the same for functions, you will have to modify function. For example, we want to add new parameter to point, let's call it `z` parameter. Without structure, we have to modify function and everywhere we call this function we have to modify call.

```
int get_distance(int x, int y, int z) {

}
```

Comment: Why pass the structures as pointers? If you want the similar effect as passing x and y separately, you should pass `struct point p`. You can also pass as `const struct* point`. But passing the struct itself might be faster on some implementations (depends on the ABI and the calling conventions),

Comment: You can pass it without pointer, but remember, then you are passing `copy` of original variable and it means stack used for variable is `sizeof(variable_type)` in this case `sizeof(struct point)`. In pointer, you pass original value and stack usage is `sizeof(type_pointer)` in this case `sizeof(struct point *)` which is always the same size no matter on what is the structure size itself. Pointer allows to modify original data, but if you use `const struct point* p` as parameter then you also prevent modifications.

Comment: @tiz0R That depends on the ABI. Many ABIs (for instance Windows __fastcall calling convention for x64) require the first few arguments to be passed in registers. The structure if is "regular" can is broken into multiple arguments and passed. So the stack usage can be zero even with this. If you want effect "exactly" similar to `(int x, int y)`m you have to do this. Passing a pointer can have other effects - For instance the original structure could get modified by some other thread. The function would then see the modified value which is not same as passing x and y,

Comment: I believe you but you must keep in mind that this is only (for example) Windows specific. Since it was not pointed out which architecture it uses I give him general answer. Using your way with structure of 10 variables in int format can fill stack on embedded device.

Comment: Linux also uses a similar convention where first 6 arguments are passed in registers. I agree that it will all be on the stack for another target like say x86 (32 bit). But also look at my second point. The behavior changes in the way you suggested.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for.

Also should is it better to include my structs into my main source, or is it safe to have it in a different source file?

Answer (score 3):

- As a thumb rule - always try to minimize variable's scope as possible. For example: if a variable is used only in one function, the only scope that it should be defined in is this function.
- Use structs to encapsulate variables of the same entity together, like offered by other answers here.
- Header files - you should have a good reason to define a variable in a header file. Usually, header files are used to *declare* function and types declarations which need to be used in several `.c` source files. If you *defined* a global variable in a `a.c` file and you want to refer it from `b.c` use `extern` for this purpose.

Also, if you could add some code our recommendations might be more specific and less thoretical.